# Отображение сайта под другим доменом

Tags: домен, хостинг

Добрый день! Представим пример: я купил домен domen.com, мне нужно чтобы при открытии domen.com отображалась страница site.ru/usa

Подскажите как это можно сделать? (можно ли это сделать без подключения домена domen.com на хостинг)?

Comment: Надо настроить проксирование (конкретней сказать без знания стоящего сервера нельзя), но это довольно тривиальная/повседневная с точки зрения веба задача.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятен вопрос.
Оба домена domen.com и site.ru/usa, принадлежат Вам? Или Вы описались и хотели написать domen.com/usa? 
В любом случае Вам нужен редирект , это возможно сделать только на хостинге.

Comment: да, оба домена будут принадлежать мне. без редиректа и хостинга никак нельзя сделать так, чтобы под domen.com отображалась например страница site.ru/usa

Comment: Нет, нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще вы можете сделать так чтобы  site.ru и domen.com - были заркалами для этого на у доменов прописываете одинаковые ns адреса, и в настройках site.ru настраиваете алиас domen.com. Конечно сразу site.ru/usa у вас не выйдет сделать копией domen.com. Но если изменить код, то такого результата возможно добиться. Проверяя домен с которого зашел пользователь, вы можете ему сразу открывать английскую версию, или русскую.